# mount using nfs4 giving no such device error

Tags: filesystems, nfs, nfs4

I am trying to mount a folder `workspace` from server to the client over NFS. For this I bind the folder to an `/export` by adding the following in my `/etc/fstab` on server:

```
/home   /export none    bind
```

Then I add the following lines in my `/etc/exports` on my server:

```
/export     *(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,fsid=0) 
/export/workspace   *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,nohide)
```

I load the exportfs file, and restart the nfs-kernel-server:

```
# exportfs -vr
# service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

I now go to my client and check which folders can be exported:

```
# showmount -e 192.168.145.131
Export list fo 192.168.145.131:
/export/workspace *
/export           *
```

But when I try mounting the folder, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.145.131:/workspace nfs/ -v
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Sat Apr 19 19:16:51 2014
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.145.131,clientaddr=192.168.145.128'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): No such device
mount.nfs4: No such device
```

I have also tried mounting `/export/workspace` and `/home/workspace` but that gives me the same error. I have tried loading the NFS module using `modprobe` on both client and server, but the module is loaded on both client and server.

Comment: What is in the logs on the NFS server? Also don't waste your time trying to use exports that don't exist!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton for your reply. The logs only showed me the same error: `no such device`. The problem lied with my kernel config file. see the details below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem after 3 days!!

I tried mounting the nfs4 server folder from a client with a newer Kernel version (3.8). I was able to do so. So I copied the configuration file `/boot/configure-3.8-generic` file to my `/usr/src/.config`, and enabled the option `Filesystems -> Network File Systems -> NFS3 client load as module` and `NFS4 client` load as module.

compiled my kernel again, created `initrd image`, updated `grub`, and now I am able to mount the server folder from my 2.6 kernel client also!

Answer (score 4):

I met the error `mount.nfs4: No such device` after a system upgrade, and later it was solved by a reboot.

It seems that the problem is that the old kernel module directory `/usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/` is deleted after the system upgrade, which causes a failure loading the module for nfs things.

Comment: Ya, for me this was caused by a kernel upgrade but not having yet rebooted. After a reboot the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Xen virtual host when I was using Ubuntu 14.04 on host providing a-too-old kernel to the virtual machine running Ubuntu 18.04, and which didn't have the /lib/modules/ for the older kernel.

I updated the kernel (to boot) to match the version (modules available) inside the virtual host, and now the kernel module loads ok, as other have found out, too.

Comment: It's good to find my own answer from stackoverflow and fix the issue with that :)